Display or Hide Table row and Column Header using Slicer in Power BI
I have a tableA and Table B. TableA has Columns ( Address, Name, City). Table B has Columns (Age, Tax, Salary). Table A and Table B are displaying over one another. Using Bookmarks I have Two buttons. Each button shows its respective Table and it gives the effect of Hiding the Other table completely.
Now I need to achieve the same using slicer because the total tables have increased to 10. I have tried many ways,

Sorting Buttons like a Slicer using Format.

Display View conttrolling on Slicer value. This hides the data rows but the header rows are always visible. In my case both tables have different header rows and the table needs to appear one over another.

The table is also exported in csv by the users of report.
Please advise.


